# Change the nature of a project with iMovie

Tags: ios-appstore, imovie

I have created a `Movie` with iMovie. I have just realised now that in fact I should have created an `AppPreview`.

Is there a way to convert my `Movie` into an `AppPreview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `AppPreview` and then copy-paste your `Movie` project to it.